# Why does using CONVERT(DATETIME, [date], [format]) in WHERE clause take so long?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running the following code on a dataset of 100M to test some things out before I eventually join the entire range (not just the top 10) on another table to make it even smaller.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM Table
    WHERE CONVERT(datetime, DATE, 112) BETWEEN '2020-07-04 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-04 23:59:59'
```

The table isn't mine but a client's, so unfortunately I'm not responsible for the data types of the columns. The DATE column, along with the rest of the data, is in `varchar`. As for the dates in the `BETWEEN` clause, I just put in a relatively small range for testing.

I have heard that `CONVERT` shouldn't be in the `WHERE` clause, but I need to convert it to dates in order to filter. What is the proper way of going about this?

Comment: Because it's not SARGable so the entire table has to be scanned; no indexes can be used to aid the RDBMS when filtering the rows. The *real* question is why are you storing something called `DATE` in a data type that isn't a `date`. The correct solution is fix your design, and store your date (and time) data in a [date (and time) data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: is there an index on that column? also based on the column. what's the datatype of your column called `DATE` in the example

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar - that's kind of the opposite side of the coin here. Even if there *was* an index on that column, applying a function to convert to a different data type destroys the option for the server to use such an index.

Comment: yeah.. I assumed the column to be datetime. then i thought why would even the OP bother to convert it to datetime and then it struck me

Comment: Be very careful with trying to use `BETWEEN` with datetime values - is it your intention to exclude anything that happened on July 4th *during* the last second of that day? It's usually far safer to use an *exclusive* end point for considering such periods (e.g. `Date < '2020-07-05T00:00:00'`, rather than the `<=` which `BETWEEN` forces on you)

Comment: Will edit my question, thanks so much!

Comment: *If* the column `date` (which isn't a `date`) is in the style 112, then that means it's in the format `yyyyMMdd`. This is, at least, a little fortunate as strings formatted in the format `yyyyMMdd` are ordered the same as a `date`. Thus you could do `WHERE DATE >= '20200704' AND DATE < '20200705';` and get the correct results. But fixing your design is what you *need* to do. For example if you ever parametrised the query and used a strongly typed date and time parameter, your performance would be awful again, unless you converted the parameters to a `varchar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to summarise my comments here, as they are "second class citizens" and thus could be removed.

Firstly, the reason your query is slow is because of the`CONVERT` on the column `DATE` in your `WHERE`. Applying functions to a column in your `WHERE` will almost always make your query non-SARGable (there are some exceptions, but that doesn't make them a good idea). As a result, the *entire* table must be scanned to find rows that are applicable for your `WHERE`; it can't use an index to help it.

The *real* problem, therefore, is that you are storing a date (and time) value in your table as a non-date (and time) datatype; presumably a `(n)varchar`. This is, in truth, a major design flaw and **needs** to be fixed. String type values aren't validated to be valid dates, so someone could *easily* insert the "date" `'20210229'` or even `20211332'`. Fixing the design not only stops this, but also makes your data smaller (a `date` is 3 bytes in size, a `varchar(8)` would be 10 bytes), *and* you could pass strongly typed date and time values to your query and it would be SARGable.

"Fortunately" it appears your data is in the style code 112, which is `yyyyMMdd`; this at least means that the ordering of the dates is the same as if it *were* a strongly typed date (and time) data type. This means that the below query will work and return the results you want:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 * --Ideally don't use * and list your columns properly
FROM dbo.[Table]
WHERE [DATE] >= '20210704' AND [DATE] < '20210705'
ORDER BY {Some Column};
```

Comment: Small typos - a date cannot be both >= july 4 and < july 4 and OP is filtering for the past year, not current year.

Comment: Must have hit `5` instead of `4`, @SMor . Should have just copied my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884073/why-does-using-convertdatetime-date-format-in-where-clause-take-so-long/67885549?noredirect=1#comment119987973_67884073)

Comment: @Larnu If I have a DateTime column and I cast it to Date ..  it will still use the index right? `WHERE CAST(CreatedOn AS DATE) = @CreatedDate`

Comment: See the answer linked to in Smor's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884073/why-does-using-convertdatetime-date-format-in-where-clause-take-so-long/67885549?noredirect=1#comment119990251_67884775), @AkshayGaonkar : [Casting is sargable but it still might not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). Just because you *can* doesn't mean you should and I also state this in the above answer: *"(there are some exceptions, but that doesn't make them a good idea)"* Use proper boundaries with `>=` and `<`.

Comment: So what's the best way to achieve my requirement? we have a lot of queries like this  and I was thinking about what to do next.. Thanks for the post..

Comment: I demonstrate that above, @AkshayGaonkar ... `WHERE [DATE] >= '20210704' AND [DATE] < '20210705'`. I give all the explanation you need above. What part of the answer don't you understand and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: In my case, the datatype is `DateTime`. I had a single parameter @CreatedDate coming into the stored procedure. So I got confused.

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar if you have your own question you should be posting your own question; but the logic is the same still; use `>=` and `<` logic. Nothing have changed. A search of how to use date boundaries in SQL will give you a wealth of resources.

Comment: `where CreatedOn >= @CreatedDate AND CreatedOn < @CreatedDate + 1` . It's so simple. Thanks, A Lot @Larnu

Comment: `@CreatedDate + 1` I (and many others) really dislike that syntax, @AkshayGaonkar , where you are treating dates like numbers. They aren't. Only the old date and time data types support that syntax too; use `DATEADD`.

Answer (score -3):

you can use like this to get better performance:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Table
WHERE cast(DATE as date) BETWEEN '2020-07-04' AND '2020-07-04' and cast(DATE as time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '23:59:59'
```

No need to include time portion if you want to search full day.

Comment: Highly unlikely to make much difference, the issue is the index not being hit

Comment: [Casting is sargable but it still might not be a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) - assuming an appropriate datatype for the column. And when cast to date style 112), the filter on time is simply nonsense (another OP issue). But it is good to mention the precision flaw.

Comment: That only applies for converted a `datetime` to a `date` though, @SMor . What the OP has is a `varchar`, and converting a `varchar` to `date` is *not* SARGable.